# Min Max dates as new columns in sql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with several columns. All I want is to join both the tables and create two more columns of min and max dates. For example

table data [columns]

```
ID   date   instrument
```

table people

```
ID  birth   country
```

All I want is join these two tables and add two more columns in the "people" table with min and max date groupby ID, as single ID contains a number of dates in data table.

Comment: That sounds good, best of luck with it.  If you have an actual question please update the question with it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may try below query -

```
SELECT P.ID, P.birth, P.country, MIN(D.date) MIN_DATE, MAX(D.date) MAX_DATE
FROM DATA D JOIN PEOPLE P ON D.ID = P.ID
GROUP BY P.ID, P.birth, P.country
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT SUB_QUERY.*,MIN(D.DATE) FROM 
(SELECT * FROM PEOPLE AS P LEFT JOIN ON DATA AS D) AS SUB_QUERY
GROUP BY P.ID
ORDER BY D.DATE ASC
```